# Working with gecko driver using python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

How to set path for the Firefox gecko driver using python?

As it very much easy to set path using Java but I am facing the problem to set path for gecko using python in Pycharm?

please help

Comment: "Facing the problem" is a very vague statement. Please specify if you are facing an error.

Comment: demouser123 - thanks for the suggestion i will improve my statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

In PyCharm, to work with Selenium 3.4.3, GeckoDriver v0.17.0, Mozilla Firefox 53.0 with Python 3.6.1 you can consider  downloading the GeckoDriver and save it  in your system and configure the absolute path of the GeckoDriver through `executable_path`.

> It is to be noted that the current Selenium-Python binding is unstable with GeckoDriver and looks to be Architecture specific. You can find the github [discussion](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3884) and [merge](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/pull/685) here. So you may additionally need to pass the absolute path of the firefox binary as `firefox_binary` argument while initializing the **`webdriver`**

Here is a sample code block which opens Mozilla Firefox 53.0 through GeckoDriver v0.17.0:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path="C:\\your_directory\\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
```

Let me know of this Answers your Question.

Comment: `executable_path` passed as a webdriver argument not refers to webdriver executable, but the browser binary itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply unzip the geckodriver and put geckodriver.exe in C:\PythonXX and you are good to go

Just use

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Note: You need a compatible version of Firefox > 48, geckodriver (good to have latest) and selenium > 3.3